# Sequence proof writing

Tags: real-analysis

If {$a_{n}$} converges to $L>0$, then {$\sqrt{a_{n}}$} is convergent with limit $\sqrt{L}$

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n\to L>0$ then for all but finitely many $n$ we have $L/2<a_n.$ When $L/2<a_n$ we have $a_n>0$ (so there is a real number $\sqrt {a_n}$ ) and $\sqrt {a_n} + \sqrt L> \sqrt {L/2}+\sqrt L=K.$ The important thing about $K$ is that it is  positive and only depends on   $L.$

Now when $L/2<a_n$ we have $$|\sqrt {a_n} -\sqrt L|=\frac {|\sqrt {a_n}-\sqrt L|\cdot |\sqrt {a_n}+\sqrt L|}{|\sqrt {a_n}+\sqrt L|}=\frac {|a_n-L|}{|\sqrt {a_n}+\sqrt L|}=$$ $$=\frac {|a_n-L|}{\sqrt {a_n}+\sqrt L}\leq \frac {|a_n-L|}{K}.$$ Now $|a_n-L|/K\to 0 ,$ and for all but finitely many $n$ we have $|\sqrt {a_n}-\sqrt L|\leq |a_n-L|/K.$ So $\sqrt {a_n}-\sqrt L \to 0.$

Comment: what does the statement "for all but finitely many n" mean?

Comment: It means the logical opposite of "for only finitely many $n$". For example, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}=(2^{-n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $0$,  so for any $r>0$ there are only finitely many $n$ for which $a_n\geq r.$ That is, for any $r>0$ the set $\{n:  a_n\geq r\}$ is finite. In other words, for any $r>0$ , we have "$a_n<r$ for all but finitely many $n$."